# ManyToManyField is not getting saved in Wagtail Page

Tags: wagtail

I have a subclass of Wagtail Page class that has field of django ManyToManyField type. When I try to create a new instance of my page object, I get a list of objects that the the ManyToManyField points to and I am able select multiple items. However, after creating that page when I try to edit the same page, it seems no data got saved for the ManyToMany field. I know in Django ModelAdmin one have to override the save_related() to save ManyToMany field data. Is there a similar method for the Wagtail Page model?

Answer (score 5):

You should define the field as a ParentalManyToManyField relation, as per the example here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/getting_started/tutorial.html#categories

This is a variant of ManyToManyField which is able to keep track of the relation in memory, allowing it to work in situations such as previewing and saving as draft (where it doesn't get saved to the normal database records).

Comment: I am trying to use the ParentalManyToManyField but I am getting this error when saving the page:  <BlogPage: test blog>" needs to have a value for field "blogpage" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Comment: Never mind. I was getting this error as I had another field that used ManyToManyField. Once I replaced that with ParentalManyToManyField it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the 'after_edit_page' and 'after_create_page' hooks to save the data for the page's ManyToMany fields.

Comment: This is likely to have unexpected results when performing actions such as previewing and saving as draft (which don't translate directly to Django's `save()` operation).